# Pipe data from multiple files into their original files

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read data from `JSON` files, compact them, and then output them back into their original files, but I'm not having much luck. The files are spread out across directories and I'm running the find command in the root directory.

The command looks like this:

```sh
find . -name '*.json' -exec cat {} \; | jq -c '.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending `find`output to a `while` loop to handle found files and using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23548686/2834978) could achieve what you expect.
Make a backup of your files since they will be overwritten.

```
#!/bin/bash
function rewrite() {
    local rfile="$1"
    echo "func : $rfile"
    local contents=$(< "$rfile")
    cat <<< "$contents" | jq -c '.' > "$rfile"
}
while read fjson ;do
    echo "$fjson"
    rewrite "$fjson"
done  < <(find $HOME/tmp -name '*.json')
```